# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. while using substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select top 10 CONVERT(nvarchar(2000),SUBSTRING(COL1,3, LEN(ISNULL(len(COL1),10)-2)),1)
from TBL
```

ERROR is

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

where COL 1 is varbinary datatype. It also has null value, so I am trying to use `ISnull` function. But it's not working.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The query is using several product specific functions.)

Comment: `select SUBSTRING(CAST(@Col1 AS nvarchar(2000)),3, LEN(ISNULL(len(CAST(@Col1 AS nvarchar(2000))),10)-2))`  or even `select SUBSTRING(CAST(@Col1 AS nvarchar(2000)),3, len(CAST(ISNULL(@Col1, 10) AS nvarchar(2000)))-2)`

Comment: I'm not sure you've correctly identified the source of this error message. Note, specifically, that it's talking about a conversion `varchar -> varbinary` (not the other way around). I can't see anywhere here where such a conversion would be attempted.

Comment: Your code works fine on a varbinary column. As per  Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment - the error is somewhere else, please share the rest of the code (e.g. do you have a where clause)